# Что можно выбрать для хранения виджетов в окне?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

У меня появилась необходимость сделать две страницы. Каждая страница должна иметь цветной фон.

В эти страницы я хочу поместить разные виджеты (надписи, кнопки и другое; наполнение первой страницы будет отличаться от наполнения второй).

При нажатии на кнопку `btn1` мне бы хотелось открывать первую страницу, при нажатии на кнопку `btn2` - вторую:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю, какой виджет лучше всего взять, чтобы осуществить такой 'контейнер'. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как его можно сделать?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button1')   # Кнопка, которая должна открывать страницу 1
        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button2')   # Кнопка, которая должна открывать страницу 2
        box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)   # Основной контейнер
        box1.addWidget(btn1, 1, 0)
        box1.addWidget(btn2, 1, 1)

        label1_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница 1', self)     # |
        label2_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Содержимое 1', self)   # |   Страница 1
        page_btn1 =QtWidgets.QPushButton('1')               # |

        #label1_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница 2', self)     # |
        #label2_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Содержимое 2', self)   # |   Страница 2
        #page_btn2 =QtWidgets.QPushButton('2')               # |

        box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()   # Контенер для виджетов страницы 1
        box2.addWidget(label1_1)
        box2.addWidget(label2_1)
        box2.addWidget(page_btn1)

        box1.addLayout(box2, 0, 0, 1, 2, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: не понятно что вы хотите сделать, объясните пожалуйста лучше.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Изменил вопрос. Если все еще непонятно, пожалуйста, напишите мне, я поправлю еще раз

Comment: `QStackedWidget` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html).

Этот виджет может размещать на себе разные виджеты, но показывать только один в данный момент:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.stacked_widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.build_page_1())
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.build_page_2())

        btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button1')  # Кнопка, которая должна открывать страницу 1
        btn1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(0))

        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button2')  # Кнопка, которая должна открывать страницу 2
        btn2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(1))

        main_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()   # Основной контейнер
        main_layout.addWidget(self.stacked_widget, 0, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        main_layout.addWidget(btn1, 1, 0)
        main_layout.addWidget(btn2, 1, 1)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def build_page_1(self):
        self.label1_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница 1', self)     # |
        self.label2_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Содержимое 1', self)   # |   Страница 1
        self.page_btn1 =QtWidgets.QPushButton('1')               # |

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label1_1)
        layout.addWidget(self.label2_1)
        layout.addWidget(self.page_btn1)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        return widget

    def build_page_2(self):
        self.label1_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница 2', self)  # |
        self.label2_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Содержимое 2', self)  # |   Страница 2
        self.page_btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('2')  # |

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label1_2)
        layout.addWidget(self.label2_2)
        layout.addWidget(self.page_btn2)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        return widget


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Я увидел вашу задачу так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Window1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(300, 200)
        self.setObjectName('window1')
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QWidget {
                background-color: #f77; 
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        ''')

        self.labelPage = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница 1', self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelContent = QtWidgets.QLabel('Содержимое 1', self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
        self.page_btn =QtWidgets.QPushButton('page_btn 1')                  

        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)              
        self.box2.addWidget(self.labelPage)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.labelContent)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.page_btn)     


class Window2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(300, 200)
        self.setObjectName('window2')
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QWidget {
                background-color: #777; 
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        ''')

        self.labelPage = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница 2', self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelContent = QtWidgets.QLabel('Содержимое 2', self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
        self.page_btn =QtWidgets.QPushButton('page_btn 2')                  

        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self) 
        self.box2.addWidget(self.labelPage)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.labelContent)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.page_btn)          


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)          # MyWindow

        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button1')   # Кнопка, которая должна открывать страницу 1
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.onClickedBtn1)
        self.btn1.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button2')   # Кнопка, которая должна открывать страницу 2
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.onClickedBtn2)

        self.window1 = Window1() 
        self.window2 = Window2()

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)        # Основной контейнер
#        box1.addLayout(box2, 0, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.window1, 0, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.btn1, 1, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.btn2, 1, 1)        

    def onClickedBtn1(self):
        self.window2.hide()
        self.box1.addWidget(self.window1, 0, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.window1.show()
        self.btn1.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn2.setEnabled(True) 

    def onClickedBtn2(self):
        self.window1.hide()
        self.box1.addWidget(self.window2, 0, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.window2.show()
        self.btn2.setEnabled(False) 
        self.btn1.setEnabled(True)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> **В вашем варианте нельзя задать фон для всех элементов, и появляются бесцветные полосы между элементами. Мне следует задать новый вопрос?**

Не надо задавать вопросы по этому поводу.
Есть таблицы стилей, где можно сделать все что вы хотите.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Window1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window1, self).__init__(parent)

        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.window.setObjectName('window1')
        self.window.setMinimumSize(300, 200)

        self.labelPage = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница 1', self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelContent = QtWidgets.QLabel('Содержимое 1', self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
        self.page_btn =QtWidgets.QPushButton('page_btn 1')                  

        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.window)              
        self.box2.addWidget(self.labelPage)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.labelContent)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.page_btn)   

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)  
        box.addWidget(self.window)


class Window2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.window.setObjectName('window2')
        self.window.setMinimumSize(300, 200)
        self.labelPage = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница 2', self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelContent = QtWidgets.QLabel('Содержимое 2', self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) 
        self.page_btn =QtWidgets.QPushButton('page_btn 2')                  
        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.window)              
        self.box2.addWidget(self.labelPage)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.labelContent)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.page_btn)   
        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)  
        box.addWidget(self.window)        


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)          

        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button1')   # Кнопка, которая должна открывать страницу 1
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.onClickedBtn1)
        self.btn1.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button2')   # Кнопка, которая должна открывать страницу 2
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.onClickedBtn2)

        self.window1 = Window1() 
        self.window2 = Window2()

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)        # Основной контейнер
        self.box1.addWidget(self.window1, 0, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.btn1, 1, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.btn2, 1, 1)        

    def onClickedBtn1(self):
        self.window2.hide()
        self.box1.addWidget(self.window1, 0, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.window1.show()
        self.btn1.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn2.setEnabled(True) 
        self.window1.setGeometry(0, 0, self.width(), self.height()-50)
        self.update()

    def onClickedBtn2(self):
        self.window1.hide()
        self.box1.addWidget(self.window2, 0, 0, 1, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.window2.show()
        self.btn2.setEnabled(False) 
        self.btn1.setEnabled(True)        
        self.window2.setGeometry(0, 0, self.width(), self.height()-50)
        self.update()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(MyWindow, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.window1.setGeometry(0, 0, self.width(), self.height()-50)
        self.window2.setGeometry(0, 0, self.width(), self.height()-50)
        self.update()


qss ='''
QWidget {
    background-color: #999; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
}
#window1{
    background-color: #f77; 
}
#window1 QLabel{
    background-color: #f55; 
}
#window1 QPushButton {
    background-color: #f33; 
}

#window2{
    background-color: #0f0; 
}
#window2 QLabel{
    background-color: #ff5; 
}
#window2 QPushButton {
    background-color: #afa; 
}
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 12, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. Жаль, что я не могу принять сразу два ответа. В обоих ответах есть одна проблема. В варианте с `QStackedWidget` можно задать цвет фона всех элементов. Но, к сожалению, `QStackedWidget` будет статичным и не меняет свой размер, при изменении размера окна. В вашем варианте нельзя задать фон для всех элементов, и появляются бесцветные полосы между элементами. Мне следует задать новый вопрос?

Comment: @MAXIM045 я добавил обновление в ответ, гляньте.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я думал, что это решается гораздо проще